# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy

```
def classify(self, texts):
        vectors = self.dictionary.feature_vectors(texts)
        predictions = self.svm.decision_function(vectors)
        predictions = np.transpose(predictions)[0]
        predictions = predictions / 2 + 0.5
        predictions[predictions > 1] = 1
        predictions[predictions < 0] = 0
        return predictions
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

occurs on the following line:

```
        predictions[predictions > 1] = 1
```

Does anyone has an idea of solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: On which line does the error occur?  You should always post your "traceback" from Python.

Comment: You made `predictions` a scalar when you assigned `predictions = np.transpose(predictions)[0]`.  Therefore, you can't index it any more as you tried to do 2 and 3 lines further down.  What **are** you trying to accomplish?!

Comment: sorry,this line"predictions[predictions > 1] = 1":
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @chen did you find the solution for your problem ? Can you show it pls ?

Comment: FWIW, I was getting and error like this with numpy 0.17 and csaps 0.11. Updating to numpy 0.19 and csaps 1.0 fixed the issue. So an upgrade may help with this `does not support item assignment` error.

Answer (score 5):

Try this testing code and pay attention to `np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)`.
It seems self.svm.decision_function(vectors) returns **1d** array instead of 2d. 
If you replace [1,2,3] to [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] everything will be ok.

```
import numpy as np
predictions = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
predictions = np.transpose(predictions)[0]
predictions = predictions / 2 + 0.5
predictions[predictions > 1] = 1
predictions[predictions < 0] = 0
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    predictions[predictions > 1] = 1
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

So, what your vectors are?

Comment: Hi Max, how to know what's the vectors are? I am using debug on Spider on the same code but I have no idea how to figure out what is inside the vectors variable

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> predictions = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
    >>> predictions
    array([1., 2., 3.])
    >>> predictions = np.transpose(predictions)[0]
    >>> predictions
    1.0
    >>> predictions = predictions / 2 + 0.5
    >>> predictions
    1.0
    >>> predictions>1
    False
```

there is no element in array is bigger than 1,So you cannot assign 1 to predictions[predictions>1],you can use ' predictions>1 ' before your assignment.

Answer (score -5):

```
predictions > 1
```

is a boolean operation.

```
predictions[predictions > 1] = 1
```

evaluates to

```
predictions[True]
```

You are looking for the [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) operator.  Your code should look like this:

```
predictions[np.where(predictions > 1)] = 1
```

Comment: This is numpy indexing (predictions[predictions > 1] = 1), this syntax can work in the correct context