# NumPy Item assignment type error: can't assign to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Very simple question, but when I run the following code I get `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment`.

```
total_array = np.array((100,2))
total_array[0][0] = 1
```

This is similar to [TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915306/typeerror-numpy-float64-object-does-not-support-item-assignment) but I believe the failure mode is different.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a 1D array, so what are you indexing with `[0]` twice?

Comment: What is your expected output after `total_array[0][0] = 1`?

Comment: My mistake, I have added the answer below and will accept in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my mistake, unlike Pytorch, numpy.array() ONLY creates 1D arrays. The correct behaviour would be to do something like total_array = np.zeros() or np.empty()

Comment: `np.array` can create 2d arrsys - if you give a nested list.  `total_array[0,0]=1` is the more idiomatic way of indexing a 2d array.